# How can I override a parent element's padding from a child

Tags: css

I have a UL nested inside a DIV, with the DIV having padding set to "0 20px".  I'd like to have this one child UL overflow over the parent DIV and extend out to the page left and right.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want the UL to expand out of the container div then you need to set the UL to have an absolute position. Dont forget to set the top and left styles to get the UL to not be up tight against the DIV as position absolute wont obey the containers div padding

Comment: I set it as absolute, with the left as 0, but now I can't get the elements beneath it to stop wrapping up.  Do I have to style them, or add in a spacer div?

Comment: this will happen, when an element becomes absolute just imagine it as popping out onto a new plane above the content but is anchored to the element below by the left and top attributes. If you know what your navigation height is going to be then you can take that height and place that on the container div padding-top. But if your navigation is dynamic and may change in height and you have content below the navigation then absolute positioning is not the way to go. If you have a demo URL or some code to show I could advise best way forward

Comment: The content is dynamic, but I got it figured out pretty easily.  I can predict the size of the content through php, so I pass that size to a spacer div and it keeps everything looking very nice.  Thanks for the help.  :)

Answer (score 19):

If you are just trying to offset the padding on the div, maybe you could achieve that by doing something like this on the UL:

```
margin:0 -20px;
```

Comment: Already tried that, I could get it to rest on the left side, but there was a space on the right.  I tried adding margin and padding on the right, and couldn't close it.

Comment: This simply will not work.  If you have an element at 100% width and you attempt to use this to remove padding from all sides, it will not make the width of the element larger, and their will still be a gap.

Answer (score 7):

```
.full-width {
   width: 100vw;
   position: relative;
   left: 49%;
   right: 49%;
   margin-left: -50vw;
   margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

Answer (score 1):

It works in the following way:

```
#parent {
position: relative; /* important */
padding: 0 25px;
}


#child {
position: absolute; /* important */
width: 100%;
margin-left: -25px;
}
```